# how to prevent overlapping of link in force directed graph?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am following [Force directed Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). How to prevent overlapping of link (line) in force directed graph. Expected output should be like 
 [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6F2G.png). Current JSON data does not contain any parent child relation ship.

Here is my Code:

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var graph = {
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
    {"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
    {"name":"Geborand","group":1},
    {"name":"Champtercier","group":1},
    {"name":"Cravatte","group":1},
    {"name":"Count","group":1},
    {"name":"OldMan","group":1},
    {"name":"Labarre","group":2},
    {"name":"Valjean","group":2},
    {"name":"Marguerite","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},
    {"name":"Isabeau","group":2},
    {"name":"Gervais","group":2},
    {"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},
    {"name":"Listolier","group":3},
    {"name":"Fameuil","group":3},
    {"name":"Blacheville","group":3},
    {"name":"Favourite","group":3},
    {"name":"Dahlia","group":3},
    {"name":"Zephine","group":3},
    {"name":"Fantine","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Cosette","group":5},
    {"name":"Javert","group":4},
    {"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},
    {"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},
    {"name":"Perpetue","group":3},
    {"name":"Simplice","group":2},
    {"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},
    {"name":"Woman1","group":2},
    {"name":"Judge","group":2},
    {"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Brevet","group":2},
    {"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},
    {"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},
    {"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},
    {"name":"Eponine","group":4},
    {"name":"Anzelma","group":4},
    {"name":"Woman2","group":5},
    {"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},
    {"name":"Gribier","group":0},
    {"name":"Jondrette","group":7},
    {"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},
    {"name":"Gavroche","group":8},
    {"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Magnon","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},
    {"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Marius","group":8},
    {"name":"BaronessT","group":5},
    {"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},
    {"name":"Enjolras","group":8},
    {"name":"Combeferre","group":8},
    {"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},
    {"name":"Feuilly","group":8},
    {"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},
    {"name":"Bahorel","group":8},
    {"name":"Bossuet","group":8},
    {"name":"Joly","group":8},
    {"name":"Grantaire","group":8},
    {"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},
    {"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},
    {"name":"Babet","group":4},
    {"name":"Claquesous","group":4},
    {"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},
    {"name":"Toussaint","group":5},
    {"name":"Child1","group":10},
    {"name":"Child2","group":10},
    {"name":"Brujon","group":4},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
    {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},
    {"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},
    {"source":11,"target":3,"value":3},
    {"source":11,"target":2,"value":3},
    {"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},
    {"source":12,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":13,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":14,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":15,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":17,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":17,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":17,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":18,"value":4},
    {"source":20,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":19,"value":4},
    {"source":21,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":20,"value":5},
    {"source":22,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":20,"value":4},
    {"source":22,"target":21,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":20,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":21,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":22,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":12,"value":2},
    {"source":23,"target":11,"value":9},
    {"source":24,"target":23,"value":2},
    {"source":24,"target":11,"value":7},
    {"source":25,"target":24,"value":13},
    {"source":25,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":25,"target":11,"value":12},
    {"source":26,"target":24,"value":4},
    {"source":26,"target":11,"value":31},
    {"source":26,"target":16,"value":1},
    {"source":26,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":27,"target":11,"value":17},
    {"source":27,"target":23,"value":5},
    {"source":27,"target":25,"value":5},
    {"source":27,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":27,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":28,"target":11,"value":8},
    {"source":28,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":30,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":31,"target":30,"value":2},
    {"source":31,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":31,"target":23,"value":2},
    {"source":31,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":32,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":33,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":33,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":34,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":34,"target":29,"value":2},
    {"source":35,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":35,"target":34,"value":3},
    {"source":35,"target":29,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":37,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":36,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":38,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":36,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":37,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":39,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":40,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":41,"target":24,"value":2},
    {"source":41,"target":25,"value":3},
    {"source":42,"target":41,"value":2},
    {"source":42,"target":25,"value":2},
    {"source":42,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":43,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":43,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":43,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":44,"target":28,"value":3},
    {"source":44,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":45,"target":28,"value":2},
    {"source":47,"target":46,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":47,"value":2},
    {"source":48,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":49,"target":26,"value":3},
    {"source":49,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":50,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":50,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":51,"target":49,"value":9},
    {"source":51,"target":26,"value":2},
    {"source":51,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":52,"target":51,"value":1},
    {"source":52,"target":39,"value":1},
    {"source":53,"target":51,"value":1},
    {"source":54,"target":51,"value":2},
    {"source":54,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":54,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":51,"value":6},
    {"source":55,"target":49,"value":12},
    {"source":55,"target":39,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":54,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":26,"value":21},
    {"source":55,"target":11,"value":19},
    {"source":55,"target":16,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":25,"value":2},
    {"source":55,"target":41,"value":5},
    {"source":55,"target":48,"value":4},
    {"source":56,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":56,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":58,"target":55,"value":7},
    {"source":58,"target":48,"value":7},
    {"source":58,"target":27,"value":6},
    {"source":58,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":58,"target":11,"value":4},
    {"source":59,"target":58,"value":15},
    {"source":59,"target":55,"value":5},
    {"source":59,"target":48,"value":6},
    {"source":59,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":60,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":60,"target":58,"value":4},
    {"source":60,"target":59,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":58,"value":6},
    {"source":61,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":61,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":61,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":62,"target":55,"value":9},
    {"source":62,"target":58,"value":17},
    {"source":62,"target":59,"value":13},
    {"source":62,"target":48,"value":7},
    {"source":62,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":62,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":62,"target":61,"value":6},
    {"source":62,"target":60,"value":3},
    {"source":63,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":63,"target":48,"value":5},
    {"source":63,"target":62,"value":6},
    {"source":63,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":63,"target":58,"value":4},
    {"source":63,"target":61,"value":3},
    {"source":63,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":63,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":64,"target":55,"value":5},
    {"source":64,"target":62,"value":12},
    {"source":64,"target":48,"value":5},
    {"source":64,"target":63,"value":4},
    {"source":64,"target":58,"value":10},
    {"source":64,"target":61,"value":6},
    {"source":64,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":64,"target":59,"value":9},
    {"source":64,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":64,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":65,"target":63,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":64,"value":7},
    {"source":65,"target":48,"value":3},
    {"source":65,"target":62,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":58,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":61,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":65,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":65,"target":55,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":64,"value":3},
    {"source":66,"target":58,"value":3},
    {"source":66,"target":59,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":62,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":65,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":63,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":61,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":60,"value":1},
    {"source":67,"target":57,"value":3},
    {"source":68,"target":25,"value":5},
    {"source":68,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":25,"value":6},
    {"source":69,"target":68,"value":6},
    {"source":69,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":27,"value":2},
    {"source":69,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":25,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":69,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":68,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":58,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":69,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":68,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":70,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":72,"target":26,"value":2},
    {"source":72,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":72,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":73,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":74,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":74,"target":73,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":69,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":68,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":25,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":70,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":71,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":64,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":65,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":66,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":63,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}
  ]
}

//d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
//});
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it is not possible for all graphs. I'm interested as to how it can be achieved in all cases where it is possible though.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006725/avoid-links-criss-cross-overlap-in-d3-js-using-force-layout

Comment: I don't think it's possible if you have branches which are connected to other branches of the same parent.  The example you showed only works in all cases where a node connects to a single parent and it's own children.

Answer (score 1):

If by overlapping you mean multiple links between two nodes then they can be resolved by drawing them as arcs with increasing curvature to separate them visually.

If by overlapping you mean edges crossing then it's only possible if your graph is planar - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing - and looking at your graph it isn't - there's at least 2 sub-graphs with almost complete connectivity. You'd need a graph layout algorithm that specifically tries to reduce edge crossings, and the bad news on that is that it's an NP-complete problem

Crossing Number is NP-Complete: DOI:10.1137/0604033
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)

Some techniques can be employed on complete sub-graphs by replacing their edge sets with confluent edges or motifs but this is stepping into graph drawing research: there's no easy answer

Confluent Drawings: Visualizing Non-planar Diagrams in a Planar Way
DOI: 10.1007/978-3-540-24595-7_1

Motif Simplification: Improving Network Visualization
Readability with Fan, Connector, and Clique Glyphs
DOI: 10.1145/2470654.2466444

In short, the only guaranteed way to not get edge crossings is not to draw edges. Maybe try looking at matrix-type visualisations for graphs? - https://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave a comment, but I don't have enough reputation, so I'm "answering" instead - sorry it's not much of an answer...

Your example of your expected output is a tree/acyclical, which more or less magically solves the issue of overlapping links. You can see in this example from Mike Bostock (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288) there isn't much link overlap just by way of the data being a tree.

So...

**if your data is a tree**, you might be lucky and the link overlapping might be a non-issue. You'll notice that the overlapping in the Bostock example happen when sibling nodes have different link distances (causing niece/nephew -- aunt/uncle link overlap). Controlling the link distances (perhaps making them a function of tree depth with longer links near the root), I *think* will prevent any overlap in your tree.

**If your data has cycles (like in the Miserables data)**, preventing overlap is much more complicated and won't just sort itself out. Like others are saying, I don't think it's possible with any D3 layout.